# Angular6 HttpInterceptor get response body

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to the get the plain text response body in an Angular6 HttpInterceptor.  My code is

```
export class HttpErrorHandlerService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        console.log('err body');
        console.log(err.error);
        return empty();
      }));      
  }
}
```

err.error at that point is a Blob with a property type "text/plain".
I'm wanting to get the response body so I can get all error messages and put them in a toast.

It looks like Angular use to return the string instead of a Blob, but I havent found out how to do this now that its changed.

Anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi could you please try the following code

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    alert(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(err.error);
```